# Emacs -- terrible font spacing

Tags: arch-linux, emacs, fonts

> System: Archlinux latest
>
> Emacs: 24.3
>
> Emacs Config config: https://github.com/jilen/prelude

Seems emacs cannot handle `Ligatures`

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a link to a higher res picture, it is impossible to see what is going on there. Also, post your `~/.Xresources`.

Comment: @jasonwryan I put the image link. And when I change to other monospaced font like `source code pro`, it is ok.

Comment: You aren't declaring that Hasklig font anywhere in your `~/.Xresources`...

Comment: In my experience, this type of display has often been related to specifying the font incorrectly.

Comment: @HalosGhost I set this font in gnome-tweak-tool and everywhere works properly with this font, expect emacs.

Comment: @jasonwryan I specify the font via `gnome-tweak-tool`

Comment: @jilen what about vim? do you have the same problem there?

Comment: @r004 gvim is fine on font-spacing, but when I type `a` it became `b` .... WTF

Comment: Post your `.emacs`, and any other relevant file (such as `prelude-settings.el`).

Comment: @jasonwryan P.S. stackexchange automatically resizes the image. If you *right-click -> open image in new tab* you can view the larger version.

Comment: @Patrick Wow: thank you! That is completely unintuitive, but very helpful. Cheers.